# How can I show popup window below RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, popupwindow

How can I show popup window below `RecyclerView` item?

I should use PopupWindow, because the menu is customized layout

See image:

[image]

Comment: I you want the pop-up to be over the list you have to get the position of the cell in the screen and position it accordingly

Answer (score 3):

`showPopUpMenu(View);` pass `View` where you want attach that popup?

```
    void showPopUpMenu(View anchor) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, anchor);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();//showing popup menu
    }
```

[**Full Demo**](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

Answer (score 2):

put this code in your viewHolder class

```
btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(btnExpand.getContext(), itemView);

                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.action_Delete:
                                    moveFile(recordName.getText().toString(), getAdapterPosition());
                                    return true;

                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    popup.inflate(R.menu.second_contect);
                    popup.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    try {
                        Field mFieldPopup=popup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                        mFieldPopup.setAccessible(true);
                        MenuPopupHelper mPopup = (MenuPopupHelper) mFieldPopup.get(popup);
                        mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    popup.show();
                }
            });
```

you can see my popupmenu

[image]

Comment: I should use PopupWindow, because the menu is customized layout.

Comment: ok.. can you plz update your answer when you succeed on PopupWindow.. bcz i also wanted to set Popupwindow instead of popupmenu..